# How to report competing app which has bypassed In-App-Purchase and started using third party payment processor

Tags: ios-appstore, in-app-purchase

I have an App that sells subscriptions to access video content (similar to Netflix). When I tried to launch with a third party payment processing tool, Apple blocked my app until I've integrated In App Purchase and completely removed the third party payment processor.

A competing app offering the same exact service, however, has launched with In App Purchase. On a later update, the competitor removed the In App Purchase option and replaced it with a third party payment processor.

The competing app, according to App Store rules, is in violation of removing In App Purchase despite selling a purely digital service.

How can I report the competing app to Apple so that they would level the playing field? The competing app to have a 30% price/cost advantage as they don't have to pay the Apple Tax.

Any answers truly appreciated <3

Comment: Contact Apple. Not our beans on here.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's App Store Review Guidelines changed in September last year, specifically regarding these types of apps, known as "reader apps". It might be that your app that was rejected earlier might be approved today.

I don't think Apple has any official contact for complaining about competitors. You have no proof that they are in violation of anything, as your competitor might have a special agreement with Apple that you know nothing of.

I would try submitting your app for approval again and see if you can pass the test this time around.